# Binding to a shadowed property on a base type

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have a WPF issue where I want to bind to a property on a base class of my view model, but the view model hides that property.

My view model hierarchy looks like this:

```cs
public class A : B {
    public new string Message => "This message will be on the screen.";
}

public class B : IMessage {
    public string Message => "This message won't be on the screen.";
}

public interface IMessage {
    string Message { get; }
}
```

I want to bind to the `Message` property defined by `IMessage`, which gets bound to `B.Message`.  However, my view model is an instance of `A`, and `A.Message` hides that property.  As expected, a naive binding resolves to `A.Message`:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" />  <!-- Binds to A.Message -->
```

How can I bind to the `Message` property defined by `IMessage`, and not `A.Message`?  Is it possible for a binding to directly reference the property of a base class or interface?

Comment: Are you using class A and B as viewmodel in different moments?

Comment: I use the base class at another view. The A class has more special View than View of B class but i don't want to make another view model because they have a lot of common parts and the same property name because of a same interface.

Comment: I've just ran your code and it works as intended. I'll make an answer and then you can check.

Comment: I missed something. You want to bind the property on the base class in your subclass. I'm sorry.

Comment: Do you want to change it in some specific event?

Comment: Just type-qualify the desired property in the property path: `{Binding Path=(local:IMessage.Message)}`.  Or, if `A` directly (re)implements `IMessage`, use `(local:B.Message)`.

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:B.Message)}" /> did the trick. 3 years working with WPF and I didn't know that. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Thanks you. Your solution the perfect answer. How can i apply your comment as answer? I can't find this option...

Comment: Voting to re-open, as this is actually a very good question with a clear answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I bind to the `Message` property defined by `IMessage`, and not `A.Message`? Is it possible for a binding to directly reference the property of a base class or interface?

When you need to bind to a property that is hidden or has an ambiguous name, you need to use the *type-qualified* property path syntax.

The segment of the path containing the hidden or ambiguous property must be enclosed in parentheses, and a type qualifier must be prepended.  Ideally, the type qualifier will be for the type *declaring* the property, but it only needs to be a type for which the property is visible and unambiguous.  In your case, either of the following should work:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:IMessage.Message)}" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:B.Message)}" />
```

This comes in handy when you need to bind to an interface property that was implemented explicitly, or in cases like yours, where the property you want is shadowed by an identically named property in a subclass.  It's also the syntax you would use to bind to an *attached property*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface-specific implementation, like this:

```
interface IA
{
    string Message { get; }
}

interface IB
{
    string Message { get; }
}

class A : B, IA
{
    string IA.Message { get { return "Foo"; }}
}

class B : IB
{
    string IB.Message { get { return "Bar"; }}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IA a = new A();
        IB b = a as IB;

        Console.WriteLine(a.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(b.Message);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Foo
Bar
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ACHhUk)

Comment: Sure, but `IB a = new A();` will display `Bar`, not `Foo`. The point is that the `new` keyword isn't polymorphism.